# tkinter Application inside NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: python, netbeans, tkinter

I install python plugin on NetBeans 8.0.2 and has try to run simple applications. All applications run as expected. But when i try to run one simple application using graphical interface (via tkinter), nothing happen. The simple windows GUI don't are displayed.

If i try to run this application in IDLE (python tool to edit and run code) , the window GUI is  perfectly displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what OS you use, but for example in linux, you usually have two pythons (2.7 and 3.x). It might be possible that IDE is using different python than the IDLE. However, tkinter was installed only for one of the two versions.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What's your question?

Comment: Hi Bryan. I use Windows and Linux, but for this particular case i used windows and I have only python 3.3.4 installed and this work nice. How i say before, the applications run correctly, inside NetBeans. But when i try to run one tkinter application inside the NetBeans, the GUI window don't displayed. The other types of application run correctly.